# Taking the floor of a real number in Z3Py

Tags: z3, z3py

Given a real number like `Real('x')` in Z3Py, how do I get its floor or ceiling? Equivalently, how do I round it? I see that `to_int` is a thing in the SMT specification, but I don't know how to call it from Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function "ToInt" takes the floor.

```
from z3 import *

x = Real('x')
print ToInt(x)
print ToInt(RealVal("1/2"))
print simplify(ToInt(RealVal("1/2")))
```

Comment: I'm curious to know how effective `ToInt`/'to_int' is when it comes to actual solver performance. Since one can code Diophantine equations using this trick (i.e., express it in reals, then assert that the fractional parts are zero), should we expect to get `Unknown` results in the presence of to_int calls more often? I understand my comment is rather vague, but wanted to hear your opinions about this.